# Kafka Multi broker setup with ec2 machine: Timed out waiting for a node assignment. Call: createTopics

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to setup kafka with 3 broker nodes and 1 zookeeper node in AWS EC2 instances. I have following *server.properties* for every broker:

kafka-1:

```
broker.id=0
listeners=PLAINTEXT_1://ec2-**-***-**-17.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT_1://ec2-**-***-**-17.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9092
listener.security.protocol.map=,PLAINTEXT_1:PLAINTEXT
inter.broker.listener.name=PLAINTEXT_1
zookeeper.connect=ec2-**-***-**-105.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:2181
```

kafka-2:

```
broker.id=1
listeners=PLAINTEXT_2://ec2-**-***-**-43.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9093
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT_2://ec2-**-***-**-43.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9093
listener.security.protocol.map=,PLAINTEXT_2:PLAINTEXT
inter.broker.listener.name=PLAINTEXT_2
zookeeper.connect=ec2-**-***-**-105.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:2181
```

kafka-3:

```
broker.id=2
listeners=PLAINTEXT_3://ec2-**-***-**-27.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9094
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT_3://ec2-**-***-**-27.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:9094
listener.security.protocol.map=,PLAINTEXT_3:PLAINTEXT
inter.broker.listener.name=PLAINTEXT_3
zookeeper.connect=ec2-**-***-**-105.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com:2181
```

zookeeper:

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
```

When I ran following command in zookeeper I see that they are connected

[image]

I also telnetted from any broker to other ones with broker port they are all connected

However, when I try to create topic with 2 replication factor I get *Timed out waiting for a node assignment*
[image]

I cannot understand what is incorrect with my setup, I see 3 nodes running in zookeeper, but having problems when creating topic. BTW, when I make replication factor 1 I get the same error. How can I make sure that everything is alright with my cluster?

Comment: 1) Why not use MSK? 2) Does it work if your listeners are set to either `PLAINTEXT://:9092` or `PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092` (you don't need different ports on different instances)

Comment: You also don't need different listener names/mappings on each broker...

Comment: 1) check pricing it is important in my case 2) When I fixed listener mapping name it is fixed. thank you!

Comment: The pricing will be almost the exact same once you add up the ingress/egress VPC traffic, EBS disk storage, and EC2 costs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's good that telnet checks the port is open, but it doesn't verify the Kafka protocol works. You could use `kcat` utility for that, but the fix includes

1. `listeners` are set to either `PLAINTEXT://:9092` or `PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:9092` for every broker, which means using the same port
2. Removing the number from the listener mapping and advertised listeners property such that each broker is the same

I'd also recommend looking at using Ansible/Terraform/Cloudformation to ensure you consistently modify the cluster rather than edit individual settings manually